# 21.10 - what's the suspend / hibernate call stack?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, acpi, 21.10

I would like to understand what is wrong with my linux system (or hardware). Sometimes I lose my session when the system is suspended, instead, it restarts then instantly without  restoring anything.

I managed to find out the following:

1. - `pm-suspend`: worked **always**
   - `echo -n mem >/sys/power/state` (invoked by `pm-suspend`): worked **always**
2. suspension when closing the lid: works most of the time
3. suspension after x minutes idling: does crash most of the time
4. `systemctl suspend` does work sometimes, sometimes is crashes my session.
5. `/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend`, which is invoked by `systemctl suspend` (as it seems) works just as often as the command above

What's the difference between those commands/actions?
why is pm-suspend reliable but the others are not?
How can I get a verbose log?

Could someone explain me how sending the system into suspend mode works currently? I am on Ubuntu 21.10 but I guess a general explanation would be fine too.

I just need a hint to get started somewhere :)

Comment: Look at [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237199/906933) - it might help you

Comment: I suggest updating UEFI before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: UEFI is, unfortunately, already at its latest version.

Comment: The question itself was quite helpful, especially seeing the `-n` on echo.  I also discovered I need to sleep for a couple seconds in order to avoid thinking I'm already awake.  In case it may be of help to others, my implementation is here: https://github.com/JeffAbrahamson/dotfiles/blob/master/i3/i3/bin/i3-lock-suspend